# Зачем angular выдаёт такую ошибку?

Tags: javascript, angular2, frontend

```
Failed to compile.

Error [ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED]: channel closed
    at ChildProcess.target.send (internal/child_process.js:588:16)
    at AngularCompilerPlugin._updateForkedTypeChecker (/home/user/Рабочий стол/lesson_proyect_angular/my-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:370:34)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/home/user/Рабочий стол/lesson_proyect_angular/my-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:208:22)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Comment: А код где? что вы запускаете? мы угадывать должны?

Comment: Код всё компилируется с первого раза, но если менять в коде что то больше 1-2х раз выдаёт эту ошибку.

Comment: Зачем выдаётся такое?

Comment: я не знаю, я не экстрасен, там в коде надо смотреть что вы меняете, где меняете и тд

Comment: Не имеет значения что я поменял, выдаёт эту ошибку и дальше уже не компелируется даже если я всё удалю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже на то, что это бага см. [это](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8349) и [это](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8331)

Comment: Я уже смотрел, решения пока нормального нету. Использую версию с предудущего проекта.

Comment: @user218635 Все верно ) нужно сделать даунгрей и ждать фикс.